# I rebuild Eclipse luna with custom methods in SWT, but inside of PDE I cant use them

Tags: eclipse, compilation

I have downloaded git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git

I added new public methods in
/eclipse.platform.swt/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse SWT/**{PLATFORM NAME}**/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/**Display.java**

Files were edited for all platforms.
After compilation of project by the command "mvn clean verify" I got custom Eclipse edition.

I have expected that eclipse give me new api for plugin development, but editor says me that IDE cant find my methods. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on the "Display" word inside of code shows me source file without my methods.

What I miss?

Comment: And how are you telling Eclipse to use this modified code?

Comment: @greg-449 In no way. I thought that eclipse uses that sources with which it was builded.

Comment: Well are you running the 'eclipse' executable and plugins that you built? What does Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform show?

Comment: @greg-449 I'm running 'eclipse' which I built. And now there is no any of my own plugins. I'm trying to create first of them inside this built ide. and this one suggests me old api.

And I cant find "Preferences" menu except one in "Window" menu. But it has no "plug-in dev" submenu.